# Real Load Replay

Tags: load-testing

Is there any term in software engineering like Real Load Replay or Real Data Replay? My manager said to me, to learn about this topic. But I have never seen this topic. Any help?

Comment: I would suggest that you ask you manager what was meant and maybe ask for some pointers where to start.

Comment: Found it. It was Database Real Application Testing :)

Comment: Can you post it as an answer to your question.

Comment: @user1837530 is it same as http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/real-application-testing/overview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It was Database Real Application Testing. 
Yes it is same "Oracle Real Application Testing"

*Oracle 11g Real Application Testing is able to capture the workload on an Oracle 10g database then replay it on an 11g database to see what has improved, remain unchanged, and what has regressed.*

Comment: Please accept your answer to show other that this was was you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Should have something to do with capturing traffics to production server and replaying it on to a test server to observe how it will perform when pushed to production.

Answer (score 0):

@ Muhammad Ali Khamis - 
Your manager talked about "performance simulation", Production Env VS Test Env.

Oracle Database replay Steps:

1. Workload capture
2. Workload pre-processing
3. Workload replay
4. Analysis and reporting

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind Real Load Replay is having a set of test data reproducing conditions and combinations from real use of the application instead of creating it from scratch.

It is very useful when you need to test inputs, web petitions and any kind of data which does not include personal nor sensitive information.

Apart from database replay, you have tools to recreate real data on other environments.

For instance, [Gor](http://leonsbox.com/blog/2013/06/04/improving-testing-by-using-real-traffic-from-production/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=twitter) is a simple tool with a listener on a production environment which sends part of this real traffic to test environments, where it is replayed.